# JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined in Windows App Development

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows

I am using Visual Studio to develop a Windows 8.1 app, using HTML, CSS, jQuery (JavaScript it allowed) as I read in the following blog that I can use jQuery to develop the app too.

http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/07/10/jquery-and-winjs-working-together-in-windows-store-apps.aspx

So, I included the jQuery 2.1.0 file inside the HTML page too as:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
```

There is no error while connecting the jQuery file:

[image]

And then the HTML codes.

Now the js is as:

```
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232509
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
                // your application here.
            } else {
                // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
                // Restore application state here.
            }
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
        }
    };

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
        // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
        // that needs to persist across suspensions here. You might use the
        // WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically
        // saved and restored across suspension. If you need to complete an
        // asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call
        // args.setPromise().
    };
    $('p').click(function () { /* <---- from here */
        $(this).html('Some text! hehehe..Sorry!');
    });
    app.start();
})();
```

I know, jQuery would only execute when I write it as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   /* '$' will be defined in this block */
}
```

But, how can I use jQuery code here inside this js function since I don't have any idea and every blog post I search for, has just the tutorial to tell me about the jQuery code usage, not how to implement it or how to make the `$` character defined.

Thanks!

Comment: $ is defined in jQuery. Did you include jQuery script file before your scripts?

Comment: Yes I have that included...

Comment: But, can you move it as first script.

Comment: move jQuery link to be the first. its important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery directive $ is undefined if jQuery library wasnt linked correctly.

make sure you link it on top, in the page's head before everything else, and make sure your relative path is correct.

Comment: yes it is. you have included default.js before jQuery, and i have a weird feeling that there is jQuery code in the default.js script, put jquery above everything and see your issue fixed.

Comment: then probably you had jQuery code in another linked script. jQuery has to be the topmost always :) if my answer helped, please consider accepting it ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're having a conflict with something else? Take a look here and see if it helps http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

Issue I find after seeing your attached image that you included jQuery but not at the top, for jQuery, $ will be defined if your jQuery file is loaded before you use it. so by moving your jQuery file at the top will solve the issue.

> [image: jq]

Comment: Nice. Visual Editor! ;)